# Executing oracle spool command which is written as a .sql file(eg:spool.sql) from c# just like executing any oracle query using OracleCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, plsql

I have a text file let us say "createfeed.sql" which contains `set` commands used in pl/sql like:

```
set pagesize,
set linesize, 
blah, 
blah,
blah,
```

Then a spool command which will create a file.

So I want to execute this createfeed.sql from C#. When I try to give the filename as OracleCommand parameter it is giving error as it doesn't go that way.

So is there any better way to execute this createfeed.sql script in C#?

One way I found was using "process" to start "pl/sql" and then execute the script but I was not able to do successfully execute the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
  string myCommand = PSQLCommand;
  //This would be the location of your file
  string myArguments = "PSQLArugments";
    Process.Start(myCommand, myArguments);

So your command would look like psql.exe \i "Path of createfeed.sql"
myCommand would = psql.exe (the full path to your executable)
myArguments = @"\i \pathToCreateFeed.sql"
```

Comment: `psql.exe` is a front-end to PostgreSQL and has nothing to do with Oracle.

Comment: But i've seen few code snippets though they were not working use process object to invoke plsql.exe and then execute the command?